# Spring Boot Exception Handler not called for parameter objects

Tags: spring-boot, exception

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.5.RELEASE and got a controller with a parameter object.

```
@GetMapping(path = SOME_PATH, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<Purchase> searchPurchases(@Valid SearchPurchaseCriteria criteria) throws ResourceForbiddenException {

}
```

The paramter object contains multiple fields but the important ones are these

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate begin;
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate end;
```

If I send and invalid date such as begin=2010-01-2 (note the missing 0) it results in a ConversionFailedException, which in turn will be mapped to a TypeMismatchException by the Spring Boot framework. Usually I can handle these exceptions using the global exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ProblemResponseExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
    protected ResponseEntity<ProblemJson> handleTypeMismatchException(TypeMismatchException ex) {
       // do something
    }

}
```

But it does not work for this exception thrown from the paramter object. I also tried to handle the ConversionFailedException directly without success either.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think that before Spring 3.2 the ControllerAdvice annotation wasn't available. You should then place your ExceptionHandler method in each controller that you want to monitor. More details here: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Comment: @Daniel: Try `HttpMessageNotReadableException` in your `ProblemResponseExceptionHandler` class instead of `TypeMismatchException`.

Comment: @Terry SpringBoot 2.2.5 comes with Spring 5, so this should not be the problem. Also all the other handlers are triggered.

Comment: @Daniel ok. So your handleTypeMismatchException is not called at all (if you put a breakpoint in it)? Did you try to have a ControllerAdvice specific to the controller handling the parameter object - meaning annotating ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = YourController.class) - ?

Comment: yeah the breapoint is not called. Mapping of parameter objects in Spring Controllers seem to take a different route. I ended up using Strings and doing the validation myself.